# Angular inject service into base class but not in sub-class and use the parent service in sub-classes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Using Angular 7 & Typescript: I have a base class that uses a lot of services and child classes (about 40 sub-class) and I don't want to add those services in all subclass constructor and pass them to `super()` but I still need to use those services in all subclass.

---

```
export class parentTool {

    constructor(type: string, public service1: Service1, public service2: Service2,public service3: Service3, public service4: Service4){}
}

export class ChildTool1 extends parentTool {

    constructor(public service1: Service1, public service2: Service2,public service3: Service3, public service4: Service4) {

        super("tool1", service1, service2, service3, service4);
    }
}

export class ChildTool2 extends parentTool {

    constructor(public service1: Service1, public service2: Service2,public service3: Service3, public service4: Service4) {

        super("tool2", service1, service2, service3, service4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: No i don't want to use eventEmitter there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use to have the same problem so I end up doing manulay DI (dependency injection) by using `injector` service

this static class use to store a refrence of injector service

```
export class AppInjector {

  private static injector: Injector;

  static setInjector(injector: Injector) {
    AppInjector.injector = injector;
  }

  static getInjector(): Injector {
    return AppInjector.injector;
  }
}
```

at app module I set the injoctor service

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(injector:Injector){
      AppInjector.setInjector(injector);// save a injector ref 
  }
}
```

> you need to store the service before you start do any DI (dependency injection)

in the base component

```
export class BaseComponent {
  protected utilitiesService: UtilitiesService; //  service
  protected loggingService: LoggingService; //  service

  constructor() {

      const injector = AppInjector.getInjector();

      this.utilitiesService = injector.get(UtilitiesService); //  DI
      this.loggingService = injector.get(LoggingService); //  DI


  }

}
```

child class now have access to all service injected by the injector class

```
    export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/component-angular-7-ecg5qh)

Answer (score 1):

Add one more service and inject all required services in there. We can simply add that service in a sub class and pass it to parent in super.

```
@injectable()
export class ParentService {
    constructor(type: string, private service1: Service1, private service2: Service2,private service3: Service3, private service4: Service4){}
    executeService1(){
        this.service1.method1();
    }
}

export class parentTool {
    constructor(private parentService: ParentService){}
}

export class ChildTool1 extends parentTool {
    constructor(public parentService: ParentService) {
        super("tool1", parentService);
    }
}

export class ChildTool2 extends parentTool {
    constructor(public parentService: ParentService) {
        super("tool2", parentService);
    }
}
```

Comment:  this is very clever solution , and if you combine this my answer will be wonderful

Comment: Thanks for this.  Is there really not a way for just to mention "parentService" in the parentTool class, rather than needing to inject it into each child class, then pass it as an argument ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global injector for preventing injecting all services in all child classes.
In your case, it will be something like this:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';
//other imports
export class parentTool {
  public service1: Service1
  public service2: Service2
  public service3: Service3
  public service4: Service4
      constructor(type: string,injector: Injector){
        this.serviceInject1 = injector.get(Service1);
        this.serviceInject2 = injector.get(Service2);
        this.serviceInject3 = injector.get(Service3);
        this.serviceInject4 = injector.get(Service4);
      }
  }

  export class ChildTool1 extends parentTool {

      constructor(injector: Injector) {  
          super(injector);
          this.service1.someMethodCall()
      }
  }

  export class ChildTool2 extends parentTool {

      constructor(injector: Injector) {  
          super(injector);
          this.service1.someMethodCall()
      }
  }
```

Comment: correct  but in my app we have so many component and we don't want to keep inject injoctor class ,check my answer