Is it possible to use dependency injection (DI) on mixins in angular?
Is it possible to use dependency injection within mixing in typescript/angular?
What I have:
export const MyMixin = <T extends Type<MyClass>>(Base: T): T =>
  class extends Base {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
    }
  };

Now I want to add the method myMethod(), which uses a Service. I try this:
 export const MyMixin = <T extends Type<MyClass>>(Base: T): T =>
    class extends Base {
      constructor(private injector: Injector, ...args: any[]) { //  throws ts-error (2545)
        super(...args);
        this.myMethod();
      }

      private myMethod(): void {
        this.injector(SomeService).doSomething();
      };
    };

Typescript doesn't like my new constructor. It throws:

A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'.ts
(2545)

A similar question was asked 4 years ago: why do typescript mixins require a constructor with a single rest parameter any[]?
Muhammed Albarmavi served a solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749960) which basically defines a global class with static methods, which serves the Injector. It works, but it feels like a anti-pattern.
Is there a solution, where I can use "clean" dependency injection on mixins?

So is this essentially a duplicate question but you don't like any of the answers there? If so then this question is very likely going to be closed as a duplicate of the one you've referenced. If not, what is different about this question from that one?

I'm generally asking if there is any way of DI on angular mixins. The question I referenced is asking how to use DI via constructor. In angular exist multiple ways of DI injection, so I want to know if any of those work for mixins.

You might want to [edit] to explain how this differs from the other question instead of leaving a comment, since comments are ephemeral (they can be deleted without a trace by moderators). Right now the question as asked still looks like this is a duplicate where you don't like the answers in the other question. In any case I wish I could help but I don't know anything about angular.  Good luck!
